# Perform action on return key of Android keyboard

Tags: android

I have an `EditText` in my app that brings up a keyboard when tapped. When the return key is pressed, I'd like to call a Java method. Is there any `boolean` or method that will allow me to perform this action? I've been looking around the [documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/EditText.html) for something that will help me, but I'm not sure exactly how to use it.

If it is not possible, is there any way to remove or disable the return key, or change it to a "Done" key on the keyboard?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use imeOptions - actionDone for EditText.

XML:

```
<EditText 
    android:id="@+id/edt_txt"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:imeOptions="actionDone"
/>
```

Activity:

```
myEdtText.setOnEditorActionListener(new OnEditorActionListener() {

    @Override
    public boolean onEditorAction(TextView v, int actionId, KeyEvent event) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        if (actionId == EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_DONE) {
            //Call your method here
            return true;  
        }

        return false;
    }
});
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Actually, I'm getting an error on all of the code after @Override. It says "unreachable statement", notably after I import the KeyEvent class.

Comment: are you adding that code after return true? @awkwardgiraffe

Comment: No, just copying and pasting the code you gave me gives me the huge error.

Comment: I pasted your code into my onCreateView() method of my fragment.

Comment: Never mind, I'm an idiot. EDIT: I added it after "return true" like MysticMagic said before. Needed to be added before.

Comment: Did you add that after `return super.onCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState);`?